# JQuery append range value to textarea once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck on a very weird problem. I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery in general, so it may sounds a bit funny but I need to add range value to the existing text in textarea, but my code adds the value on every range input, but I need only one entry to change dynamically on input.

Here's the code I have :

```js
$("input").on("input",function(){
    $("textarea").append(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Test</textarea>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

Thank you very much for spending your precious time dealing with my problem. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Please do not post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include a "code snippet", right here in your question to provide an executable bit of code.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this;

```js
var text = $("textarea").val();
$("input").on("input",function(){
 $("textarea").val(text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Test</textarea>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: Please do not post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include a "code snippet", right here in your answer to provide an executable bit of code. Also, provide explanations with your code. Just posting code that works doesn't really "answer" anything.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I saw your Fiddle, well it works just like I want it to, thank you)